# WTForms validator for both URL and IP address

Tags: python, flask-wtforms

How can I have an string field that can accept both an IP address and URL?

```
address = StringField("Address", [
    validators.InputRequired(),
    validators.URL(require_tld=False), # Either this
    validators.IPAddress() # or this one
])
```